Blazor 8 InteractiveServer and Auth
I'm working on a Blazor project and when i try @rendermode InteractiveServer an exception is thrown on Authorized pages.
I'm trying to get some components working, and they work if I test on the /Home @rendermode InteractiveServer it works fine. When the same code is on an Authorized page, it breaks.
Here's a simple example of the code I'm trying to run:
<div>
    Checked: @TheValue
    <InputCheckbox @bind-Value="@TheValue" />
    <label for="DemoCheckbox">Checkbox</label>
</div>

@code{

    public bool TheValue { get; set; } = true; 

}```

So I'm trying to find how to get `@rendermode InteractiveServer` working on an Authorized page, or if there is some other way to get my components working there.

Thanks,

I was expecting the above checkbox to work without adding rendermode as  I have working components such as a file upload with a submit button that works fine. Setting rendermode breaks the page.


There's simply not enough code and context here to provide an answer.  It will work on a properly configured site.  You need to work on [MRE] to demonstrate the problem Working on the [MRE] often helps you solve the problem yourself.

I'm not sure what you mean by "There's simply not enough code..." and also saying I need to on "minimal reproducible example" The checkbox code I shoed as an example is pretty simple. Using Blazor 8 with Authentication, it works on non-authenticated pages, such as the home page. On the authenticated index page, this very simple code example does not work. If I add '@rendermode InteractiveServer', an exception is thrown. I'm looking to see how to get such a simple example of code to work on authenticated pages.
